# PHP garbage collector on resource?

Tags: php, resources, garbage-collection

take this simple loop

```
while(1) {
    $data = file_get_contents('randomfiles.img');
    $resource = imagecreatefromstring($data);

    //> do some image operation and other stuff
    //> continue

    //> not calling imagedestroy($resource);

}
```

As you can see I didn't called imagedestroy, but I am using the same variable ($resource) to store the input of `imagecreatefromstring();` (type resource)

When a new loop starts the php GC free the previous `$resource` automatically?

Let's consider only PHP 5.3+

Thanks

Comment: *(reference)* [Garbage Collection](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/features.gc.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php

> #### Freeing resources
>
> Thanks to the reference-counting system introduced with PHP 4's Zend Engine, a resource with no more references to it is detected automatically, and it is freed by the garbage collector. For this reason, it is rarely necessary to free the memory manually.
>
> *Note: Persistent database links are an exception to this rule. They are not destroyed by the garbage collector. See the persistent connections section for more information.*

Comment: @yes note that the Garbage Collector will not kick in immediately when the ref-count drops to zero. If you want to make sure the resource is destroyed, the safest way is still to use `imagedestroy()`

Comment: I don't care if they are not instantly freed. the important is that script doesn't overcome memory_limit

Answer (score 5):

Now if the resource was a regular PHP object the it would be freed.

But since you're dealing with GD library objects, it really depends on the implementation of GD. GD lib might be allocating additional memory againt that image "handle", which it would only free when you call `imagedestroy()`. (I understand that GD Lib is actually a library implemented in C, with PHP bindings).

If you think that you might forget to call `imagedestroy()`, it is best you create a wrapper class around your `$resource`, and call `imagedestroy()` in the destructor.